# Analytic Branches

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

How would I show that there exists an analytic branch of $$(1-cosz^2)^\frac{1}{4}$$ near $z=0$? My initial thoughts is to use power series expansion since, the expansion of $cos z $ converges for all $z$. This gives $$(1-cosz^2)^\frac{1}{4} = 2^{\frac{-1}{4}}z + 24^{\frac{-1}{4}}z^2+...$$
But now how do i show the existence of an analytic branch?

Comment: can $(z^2+z^4)^{1/2}$ be analytic at $z=0$ ? the proof is the same here, since $1-\cos(z^2) = 1-(1-\frac{z^4}{2} +z^8 h(z^2)) = \frac{z^4}{2} - z^8 h(z^2)$ with $h(z)$ analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: @Rooney Your second term should be a $z^5$ term.

Comment: by choosing the branch such that $(z^k)^{1/k} = z$ (which is impossible if $z \to z^{1/k}$ is a normal function, and not a multi-valued function), and if $h(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$, then $(z^k + z^{k+1} h(z))^{1/k} = z (1+z h(z))^{1/k}$ is analytic at $z=0$ since $f(z)^{1/k}$ is analytic on any open where $f(z) \ne 0$.